# Максимальное количество элементов общего подмассива с одинаковой суммой

Tags: python, алгоритм

Нужно реализовать функцию возвращающую количество самого длинного подмассива двух массивов с одинаковой суммой.
Пример:

```
arr_1 = [1, 2, 3, 2, 1]
arr_2 = [3, 2, 1, 5, 6]
# Функция должна вернуть 3 так как 1 + 2 + 3 == 3 + 2 + 1
arr_3 =  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
arr_4 = [4, 5]
# Функция должна вернуть 2, так как 4 + 5 == 4 + 5
```

Функция, которая решает данную проблему и нуждается в оптимизации - уменьшении сложности алгоритма:

```
def  total_subarray(string1, string2):
    rows = [[0 for _ in string1] for _ in range(2)]
    tmp_row = [0 for _ in string1]
    result = 0
    for i in range(len(string2)):
        for j in range(len(string1)):

            if string2[i] == string1[j]:
                rows[1][j] = 1

                if j:
                    rows[1][j] = rows[0][j-1] + 1
                
                if rows[1][j] > result:
                    result = rows[1][j]

        rows[0] = rows[1]
        rows[1] = tmp_row[:]

    return result
```

Прошу подсказки, в какую сторону думать, полагаю что нужно использовать алгоритм Кадана (префиксные суммы).

Comment: В данном случае подмассив - это непрерывный подотрезок массива?

Comment: А как в задаче проявляет себя условие "Общий подмассив"? Очевидно, что если подмассив общий, то его сумма одинакова в обоих массивах, а если это два разных подмассива с одинаковой суммой, то что делать, если у них разная длина: [1, 1, 1], [3]?

Comment: @EzikBro, да это так

Comment: @EzikBro, общий подмассив должен быть одинаковой длины

Comment: То есть в моем примере ответ 0?

Comment: Ваша собственная функция дает неверный ответ уже на первом же моем тесте: `>>> total_subarray([1, 2, 3, 2, 1], [3, 1, 2])   #2`. Ну а я навскидку не могу придумать решения быстрее `n^2*log(n)`, и практически уверен, что решения быстрее `n^2` вообще не существует. Какие конкретно требования к скорости функции?

Comment: @EzikBro, да, именно так

Comment: Количество подмассивов будет n*n, быстрее просто не получится